# SQL: USING TIMESTAMP in WHERE CLAUSE in SQL

Tags: sql, where-clause

I need to filter the results to see 2023 data only. But my WHERE clause also captures data in 2024 and I'm not sure what's causing this issue.. Anyone know what I need to fix in order to just view results in 2023? Btw - dates are shown as string in my dataset.

```
SELECT id, name, performance, record_date
FROM records
WHERE date_parse(record_date,'%Y-%m-%d') >= DATE_ADD('year', -1, TIMESTAMP '2024-01-01 00:00:00')
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: And another `and` to your where clause to limit to 2023 only. As you currently have it, appears you are simply stating "all dates past this date". Or better yet, just replace that line with the appropriate way to extract year from your column. Depends on your DBMS.

Comment: Get just the **year** of your `record_date` and check for equality with the desired one.

Comment: What is the exact data type of your `record_date` column? In who database engine? “ dates are shown as string” has no meaning. Be specific and factual.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to parse date or dateadd to get data for 2023. Simply check the year:

```
SELECT id, name, performance, record_date
FROM records
WHERE year(record_date) = 2023;
```

EDIT: What if it is a string, and\or required to operate on a date range?

Then parse the date and still check the year. ie:

```
SELECT id, name, performance, record_date
FROM records
WHERE year(date_parse(record_date,'%Y-%m-%d')) = 2023;
```

If need a date range check, for example all in January, Feb and March in 2023:

```
SELECT id, name, performance, record_date
FROM records
WHERE date_parse(record_date,'%Y-%m-%d') >= date_parse('2023-01-01','%Y-%m-%d')
  and date_parse(record_date,'%Y-%m-%d') < date_parse('2023-04-01','%Y-%m-%d');
```

Note that we want all up to excluding April 1st, 2023 midnight.

Comment: Thanks! But what if record_date is shown as string?

Comment: @Crystal, that would be a bad design, but stiil you could parse to date and check its year. If you want a date range then check if it is >= start and < end (end is a datetime that would be excluded). I can give you a sample like that if you need.

Comment: That would be great!

Comment: Using a function in where clause is sub optimal (unless your RDBMS intelligently converts it to a full date)

Comment: @Crystal, edited, assuming it was a string date.

Comment: @SalmanA how many nanoseconds of optimization are we seeking here. Then it would have other aspects like what indexes you have,  Is it a timeseries data etc

Comment: @SalmanA, and BTW, the reason I didn't provide a more optimized code is also becaue I don't even know the backend.